# Colour Errors / Warnings / Information in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors, ansi-term

So I have the following variables defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
RS="\033[0m"    # reset
HC="\033[1m"    # hicolor
UL="\033[4m"    # underline
INV="\033[7m"   # inverse background and foreground
FBLK="\033[30m" # foreground black
FRED="\033[31m" # foreground red
FGRN="\033[32m" # foreground green
FYEL="\033[33m" # foreground yellow
```

And when I do an `echo -e "$FRED Red"` *at the prompt*, I actually get `Red` in red on gnome-terminal, but when I execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "$FRED Red"
echo -e "$FYEL Yellow"
echo -e "$FGRN Green"
```

I get everything in the default colour even though `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

[screenshot including exact output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV6VA.png)

*What am I doing wrong?*

<sub>**Note:** Eventually I want to echo Errors in red, Warnings in yellow and Info in green in my scripts.</sub>

Comment: That is dependent on your terminal/$TERM. I suspected it and tested in in fluxbox/lxterminal and it shows colours in both cases. Depending on ssh confs/software/plataform your TERM can and will change. Would you add $TERM contents on both cases?

Comment: edited @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: Try `TERM=xterm` at the top of the script just for testing it out.

Comment: Not a Mac. [New Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5RqKS.png)

Comment: Alternative way to colour code error messages etc (I haven't tried it yet though): https://superuser.com/questions/542074/how-can-i-customize-the-color-of-error-messages-in-bash#answer-542917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file are not exported.  The file is read by any interactive non-login shell, but not by shell scripts (these are non-interactive).

Since the variables are not exported, they are not available in the environment of your script.

I would suggest *not* modifying the distribution-provided file `/etc/bash.bashrc` and instead:

- add the variables in the script itself (where they don't need to be exported), or
- add them (and export them) in your personal `.bashrc` file, or
- add them (and export them) in a separate `.sh` file under `/etc/profile.d` which would export the variables for any login shell.  A login shell is started either by your terminal application, or by your graphical environment when you log in (or both).

If you add the variables *anywhere* other than in the script itself (in a file not explicitly sourced by the script), then the variables would not be available if you run the script from `cron`.

Comment: Adding the `export COLOR=ANSI_CODE` to `/etc/profile.d/ansi-colours.sh` and logging out and back in did the trick!  Thanks!